# Output scientific notation as decimal notation

Tags: lisp, number-formatting

I'm using http://www.solve-et-coagula.com/As3Lisp.html to run a basic factorial function.

It's outputting the results in scientific notation, but I'd like to see the full "expanded" number.

```
(defun factorial (n)
 (cond ((= n 0) 1)
       (t (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

then

```
(factorial 100)

9.33262154439441e+157
```

I've tried various `format` commands, `(format t "~D" (factorial 100))` looks like the winner but it doesn't work.  Also tried setting `(setq *READ-DEFAULT-FLOAT-FORMAT* 'double-float)` but still doesn't work.

Is the problem with my commands, or is it the environment?

Comment: Who knows what kind of Lisp this is and what the implementation provides? If you are interested, why not ask the author?

Comment: I'm just starting out so I'm not sure how "interested" I am yet :)  Mostly would just like to know how to get it working so I have a reliable place to start.  From your comment, it sounds like changing environments could help?

Comment: If you want to learn Lisp, I would propose to use a Lisp implementation with some documentation available. Using an established dialect like Common Lisp or Scheme would help, too.

Comment: @wxvw - ahh, that's the solution I was looking for.  Will accept as solution if posted.

Comment: The link `http://www.solve-et-coagula.com/As3Lisp.html` is dead (404).  I'd be curious to see what it pointed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a different environment will do the trick.

I used Gnu Common Lisp (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~novak/gclwin.html) and the answer is returning as expected.

Comment: I hadn't heard of GCL before this post. Wikipedia says that GCL isn't yet fully compliant with the CL spec. I don't know how much stock to take in that statement on wikipedia... But there are other fully-compliant alternatives if you are going to install a CL environment on your machine: Clozure Common Lisp (CCL), Steel-Bank Common Lisp (SBCL), CMUCL, for starters.

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation supports [srfi-28](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-28/srfi-28.html) (format) then i think ~F will do the trick.
On chicken scheme:

```
#;1> (use format)
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/format.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/chicken.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-13.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/data-structures.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/ports.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/extras.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/6/format.so ...
#;2> (format #t "~F~%" (factorial 100))
93326215443944100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0
#t
```

check out the [format egg specification](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/format)

cheers.